# Filter YouTube videos by category

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, youtube

I'm currently working on a project that displays an array of YouTube trending videos from several regions. Currently I'm working on a function that allows users to filter out results by category, and have no honest clue about where to begin implementation.

Here's a snippet of the video category data for the US region:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoCategoryListResponse",
 "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/S730Ilt-Fi-emsQJvJAAShlR6hM\"",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/Xy1mB4_yLrHy_BmKmPBggty2mZQ\"",
   "id": "1",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Film & Animation",
    "assignable": true
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
   "etag": "\"m2yskBQFythfE4irbTIeOgYYfBU/UZ1oLIIz2dxIhO45ZTFR3a3NyTA\"",
   "id": "2",
   "snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Autos & Vehicles",
    "assignable": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Also attached is the function that takes in the search input and the type of search and returns an array storing the wanted search results:

```
function searchFunction(input, searchParameter, region) {
   if (!input) { return []; }

   return videos[region]
      .filter(x => {
         if ((x[searchParameter]).toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())) {
            return x[searchParameter];
         }
      })
      .map(x => {
         var data = { "title": x.title, "channel_title": x.channel_title, "views": x.views, "likes": x.likes, "dislikes": x.dislikes, "thumbnail_link": x.thumbnail_link };
         return data;
      })
      .reduce((acc, x) => { return acc.reduce((acc, xx) => acc || xx.title == x.title, false) ? acc : [...acc, x]; }, []);
}
```

I was originally thinking to parse through each region's category list and pull the `title` from there; however, as our `video` variable stores the `category_id`:

```
// parsing data before it (video & channel title, trending date)
[str, rest] = next(rest);
video.category_id = parseInt(str);
// parsing data after it (like/dislike count, # views/comments, etc.)
```

would it be necessary to extract data from the data? Was going to implement this filter with a dropdown menu on HTML/CSS, filter videos by one particular category (and not multiple).

**Update (1 May)**

Very slowly starting to craft a solution. I have implemented a checkbox list of the categories:

```html
<select class="inputclass" name="category" id="category">
    <input type="checkbox" name="Film & Animation" value="1" onchange="">Film & Animation<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Autos & Vehicles" value="2" onchange="">Autos & Vehicles<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Music" value="10" onchange="">Music<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Pets & Animals" value="15" onchange="">Pets & Animals<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sports" value="17" onchange="">Sports<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Short Movies" value="18" onchange="">Short Movies<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Travel & Events" value="19" onchange="">Travel & Events<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Gaming" value="20" onchange="">Gaming<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Videoblogging" value="21" onchange="">Videoblogging<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="People & Blogs" value="22" onchange="">People & Blogs<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Comedy" value="23" onchange="">Comedy<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Entertainment" value="24" onchange="">Entertainment<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="News & Politics" value="25" onchange="">News & Politics<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Howto & Style" value="26" onchange="">Howto & Style<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Education" value="27" onchange="">Education<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Science & Technology" value="28" onchange="">Science & Technology<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Nonprofits & Activism" value="29" onchange="">Nonprofits & Activism<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Movies" value="30" onchange="">Movies<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Anime/Animation" value="31" onchange="">Anime/Animation<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Action/Adventure" value="32" onchange="">Action/Adventure<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Classics" value="33" onchange="">Classics<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Documentary" value="35" onchange="">Documentary<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Drama" value="36" onchange="">Drama<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Family" value="37" onchange="">Family<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Foreign" value="38" onchange="">Foreign<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Horror" value="39" onchange="">Horror<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Sci-Fi/Fantasy" value="40" onchange="">Sci-Fi/Fantasy<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Thriller" value="41" onchange="">Thriller<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Shorts" value="42" onchange="">Shorts<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Shows" value="43" onchange="">Shows<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Trailers" value="44" onchange="">Trailers<br>
</select>
```

The function should access `value` in checkbox and compare it to `category_id` in the `videos` array with our search results.

**Update 2 (2 May)**

A little deviation from original implementation plans. Once categories are checked on the list, a button is pressed that filters the results and displays them on the page. `onClick` would call said function.

```
<button class="inputclass" id="filterBtn" onClick="">
   Filter
</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks much, and apologies in advance if this is confusing.

Comment: A general rule: If it's not a string, then it's not JSON. What you are showing here are regular JavaScript objects. JSON can be used to represent those objects, or transfer them e.g. in an API response, but the objects *themselves* are not JSON. They are data. (I've removed the JSON references from the question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list of `video` objects, each of which has a category ID, and a list of category IDs.

The filtering process is very simple:

```
function filterVideosByCategory(videos, categoryIds) {
    return videos.filter(vid => categoryIds.includes(vid.category_id));
}
```

When `categoryIds` is an array of numeric IDs, there is nothing else you need to do to get a filtered list.

For getting this array from the HTML UI, it really helps if all your checkboxes have the same name:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="1">Film &amp; Animation<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="2">Autos &amp; Vehicles<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="10">Music<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="15">Pets &amp; Animals<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="17">Sports<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="18">Short Movies<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="19">Travel &amp; Events<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="20">Gaming<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="21">Videoblogging<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="22">People &amp; Blogs<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="23">Comedy<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="24">Entertainment<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="25">News &amp; Politics<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="26">Howto &amp; Style<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="27">Education<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="28">Science &amp; Technology<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="29">Nonprofits &amp; Activism<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="30">Movies<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="31">Anime/Animation<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="32">Action/Adventure<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="33">Classics<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="35">Documentary<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="36">Drama<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="37">Family<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="38">Foreign<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="39">Horror<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="40">Sci-Fi/Fantasy<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="41">Thriller<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="42">Shorts<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="43">Shows<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="category" value="44">Trailers<br>
```

This way you can pick up the IDs in one go (I'm assuming you have included jQuery for the following sample):

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[name=category]', function () {
    var categoryIds = $('input[name=category]:checked').toArray().map((elem) => +elem.value);

    // work with the IDs...
    console.log(categoryIds);
});
```

The `+` in `.map((elem) => +elem.value)` is a shorthand that turns the element value (which is a string in HTML) into a number.

Comment: Am using Node.JS to handle data requests; I imagine the code snippet from above is implemented on server js in a substantial way

Comment: @eb3rt If you're doing this on the server side, disregard the jQuery sample.

Comment: In that case, how would one go about picking up the IDs server-side?

Comment: @eb3rt The client posts the form's contents, the server takes the IDs from that form post. Let's try not to turn the comments here into an HTTP. crash course. This wasn't part of your question, there are many good tutorials and tons of examples on that topic available, and last but not least, the comment section is a horrible format for interactive lectures anyway.

Comment: Regarding "wasn't part of your question": Stack Overflow is a "question & answer" format. You've updated your question twice now, and each time it got a new spin. That's not how it is supposed to work. One question, one answer. Got another question? Write a new post. But it seems to me that you're lacking many basics at the moment, and that you're not sure yourself yet how you even want to implement your idea. I recommend you take a step back and work through a couple of tutorials first that give you an idea how HTML forms work, how HTTP works, and how it all integrates with node.js.